# onUpdated vs nextTick

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am trying to understand the difference between `onUpdated` and `nextTick`. i created the below posted example.actually, i expected the text displayed inside `onUpdated` for both of the 1st click and the 2nd click is to be the same, because as stated in the docs [here](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated)

> Registers a callback to be called after the component has updated its DOM tree due to a reactive state change

according to my understanding, the DOM-tree is the virtual DOM in which all the DOM nodes are to be updated first before these updates are applied on the actual DOM. the `onupdated` will be called when the virtual DOM is updated and while the updates are not
yet reflected or applied on the the actual DOM. if we want to see the updates reflected on the actual DOM,`nextTick` must be used

for the aforementioned reasons, i expected that the text in `handleClick`, `onBeforeUpdate` and `onupdated` are to be the same.

please correct me if i misunderstood the difference between `onUpdated` and `nextTick`

**code**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="handleClick">Insert/Remove</button>
    <div v-if="show" ref="content">I am an element</div>
  </div>

</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, ref} from 'vue' 
import { onBeforeMount,onMounted,onUpdated,onBeforeUpdate } from 'vue'

const show = ref(true)
const content = ref()
const state = reactive({count: 0})

const handleClick = () => {
  show.value = !show.value
  console.log("handleClick:",show.value, content.value)
  // nextTick(() => {
  //   // console.log(show.value, content.value)
  // })
}

onMounted(()=>{
  console.log("onMounted");
})

onBeforeUpdate(()=>{
  console.log("onBeforeUpdate.show.value, content.value:",show.value, content.value)
})
onUpdated(()=>{
  console.log("onUpdated.show.value, content.value:",show.value, content.value)
})
```

**output**

```
//after first click on Insert/Remove->handleClick
handleClick: false <div>​I am an element​</div>​
App.vue:80 onBeforeUpdate.show.value, content.value: false <div>​I am an element​</div>​
App.vue:83 onUpdated.show.value, content.value: false null

//after 2nd click on Insert/Remove->handleClick
handleClick: true null
App.vue:80 onBeforeUpdate.show.value, content.value: true null
App.vue:83 onUpdated.show.value, content.value: true <div>​I am an element​</div>​
```

Comment: _” reasons, i expected that the text in handleClick, onBeforeUpdate and onupdated are to be the same.”_ But than the `onUpdated` would not have much use, would it? `onUpdated` reflects the state in the virtual DOM, after the update. DOM updates are asynchronous and Vue may wait for multiple updates to patch the DOM. `nextTick` is waiting for the real DOM update.

Comment: @Gabe thanks,would you please answer this question if possible?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303415/dom-update-vs-component-re-render

Comment: Look here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html and here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/vue-next-tick/